# Getting the error Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component after implementing react-select

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

I've recently been learning React more and these hooks have been causing me a few issues that I know are probably not the biggest errors. But as I was adding in more fields with the react-select library, I started getting:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

*I've already tried installing Eslint with their react-hooks and got no hits though this is the error I get when I run the site.*

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from 'react-select';
// This will require to npm install axios
import axios from 'axios';

const weekOptions = [
    { value: 0, label: 'Sunday'},
    { value: 1, label: 'Monday'},
    { value: 2, label: 'Tuesday'},
    { value: 3, label: 'Wednesday'},
    { value: 4, label: 'Thursday'},
    { value: 5, label: 'Friday'},
    { value: 6, label: 'Saturday'},
]

export default class Create extends Component {
  // This is the constructor that stores the data.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Method binders
    this.onChangeLocation = this.onChangeLocation.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDeliveryLead = this.onChangeDeliveryLead.bind(this);
    this.onChangeTruckSize = this.onChangeTruckSize.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDeliveryAvailability = this.onChangeDeliveryAvailability.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDeliveryFee = this.onChangeDeliveryFee.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    // Setting default state
    this.state = {
      loc_location: "",
      loc_lead_time: "",
      loc_truck_size: "",
      loc_delivery_fee: "",
      loc_delivery_availability: [],
    };
  }

  // These methods will update the state properties.
  onChangeLocation(e) {
    this.setState({
      loc_location: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangeDeliveryLead(e) {
    this.setState({
      loc_lead_time: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangeTruckSize(e) {
    this.setState({
      loc_truck_size: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangeDeliveryFee(e) {
    this.setState({
      loc_delivery_fee: e.target.value,
    });
  }

  onChangeDeliveryAvailability(selectedOptions) {
    this.setState({
      loc_delivery_availability: selectedOptions
    });
    console.log(selectedOptions); // Testing
  }

// This function will handle the submission.
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // When post request is sent to the create url, axios will add a new record(newperson) to the database.
    const newLocation = {
      loc_location: this.state.loc_location,
      loc_lead_time: this.state.loc_lead_time,
      loc_truck_size: this.state.loc_truck_size,
    };

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/location/add", newLocation)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));

    // We will empty the state after posting the data to the database
    this.setState({
      loc_location: "",
      loc_lead_time: "",
      loc_truck_size: "",
      loc_delivery_fee: "",
      loc_delivery_availability: [],
    });
  }

  // This following section will display the form that takes the input from the user.
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <h3>Create New Location</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Position of location: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.loc_location}
              onChange={this.onChangeLocation}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Max Delivery Lead Time: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.loc_lead_time}
              onChange={this.onChangeDeliveryLead}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Truck Size: </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.loc_truck_size}
              onChange={this.onChangeTruckSize}
            />
          </div>
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Delivery Availability: </label>
          <Select 
              options={weekOptions}
              value={this.state.loc_delivery_availability}
              onChange={this.onChangeDeliveryAvailability}
              isMulti={true}
              placeholder="Search days of the week"
          />
          </div>
          
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Create New Location"
              className="btn btn-primary"
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A quick fix and maybe a small explanation with at least how it pertains to the error I've been having would help me out a lot. Thank you.

Comment: This `Create` component doesn’t seem to use a hook, are you sure it’s related to the error? The error should have included a stack trace pointing to the file and line that caused the problem. But in general, hooks can only be used in function components. `Create` is a class component and therefore cannot use hooks.

Comment: I'll look into the stack. It does list this as the error but also three other reasons which I don't believe are related to the hooks either.
`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, it was something small. I had **node_modules installed in another layer higher than my ./client directory and the react-select module I was using was also in that project-level directory instead of the client one.** Therefore it was causing *multiple* versions of React and also the client code couldn't use react-select properly. *It's all working now though!*